# How to render erb/html on the fly with a layout? Non-Rails app

Tags: ruby, erb, rack

I have a rack app. In it there's a layout file and *.html.erb file. **How can I render these 2 and get html as the output? On the fly, that is.**

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ERB`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html):

```
require "erb"
@name = "John"
ERB.new("Hi, <%= @name %>!").result binding
```

Comment: I don't have pure html as a string, but a) layout b) html file

Comment: I am not sure I understand what “html file” within this context means, but you always can read a file and get a string.

Comment: a) layout file b) html file

Comment: Meaning, the layout/skelleton file and normal html file should be tie together to produce html. on the fly

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html -- this isn't on the fly

Comment: If they should be tied together, feel free to tie them. The above perfectly answers the question stated and I am not going to write the code for you.

Comment: no, it doesn't. I didn't ask about rendering a html string

Comment: It does, you simply don’t understand it.

Comment: You know what I'm asking about better than I do?